# 8051: JMP instruction works in an unexpected way

Tags: assembly, embedded, microcontroller, 8051

I'm working with 89C51 in Keil uVision.

I've somehow acquired the habit of using

```
JMP label   ; goto label
```

According to the datasheet, `JMP` should be written as `JMP @A+DPTR`, and for what I'm using it, the `SJMP`, `LJMP` and `AJMP` should be used.

Nonetheless, the way I use it *works just fine*.

The question is, why? Is that some uVision's addition to the language?

Comment: Examine the generated machine code. I guess it's just a feature of your assembler so it generates the most appropriate instruction, but couldn't find anything in the manual about it.

Comment: I think it's just a better way to use the `JMP` instruction if you're using a jump table.

Comment: Okay I checked the hex file and it's compiled to SJMP (maybe other types too, this is the one I found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an optimization that inserts the appropriate jump instruction so you don't have to determine which is required.

From the [Ax51 User's Guide](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_wp_pgmaddress.htm):

> Generic jumps and calls are two instruction mnemonics that do not
>   represent a specific opcode. JMP may assemble to SJMP, AJMP, LJMP or
>   EJMP. CALL may assemble to ACALL, LCALL or ECALL. These generic
>   mnemonics always evaluate to an instruction, not necessarily the
>   shortest, that will reach the specified program address operand.

If you desire a specific type of jump, you can always use the corresponding mnemonic.